# Where is WordPress on HostGator?

Tags: wordpress, plesk, homepage, hostgator, installation

I installed WordPress in my domain's directory on HostGator, but when I go to this domain, it goes to a page for Plesk.  Can someone tell me how to direct my homepage to point to my WordPress installation?  I didn't find anything to help with this in the WordPress Toolkit information.

Comment: Have you tried to ask their customer support?  I doubt that any of our regulars will know the answer to this question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller:  I didn't try to contact them yet, but I will now.  Thanks for your honest answer, it helps!

Comment: @WebQuest Whenever you get the default page for Plesk, that means that something is misconfigured, or the server just needs to be restarted if you made a change (sometimes just restarting the Apache process is enough).